# ethereum smart contract code question

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract MemoryAndStorage {
    mapping(uint => User) users;
    struct User{
        uint id;
        uint balance;
    }

    function addUser(uint id, uint balance) public {
        users[id] = User(id, balance);   
    }

    function updateBalance(uint id, uint balance) public {
        User storage user = users[id];
        user.balance = balance;
    }

    function getBalance(uint id) public view returns (uint) {
        return users[id].balance;
    } 

}
```

I have questions about the updateBalance function.

Question 1) As we know , there're pointers (storage pointers and memory pointers) and there're actual datas. First I am interested, if both storage pointer and the data that pointer is actually pointing to are both saved in storage?

Question 2) so in a function updateBalance, where does user variable got created that's pointing to users[id]?

Question 3) if I wrote the `User memory user = users[id];` would that variable got created in memory storage and it would watch the data that'is in storage ?

Question 4) If I write the following : `User storage user = User(5,10);` there's an error. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/03/09/understanding-ethereum-smart-contract-storage/ will answer most of your questions.

The key takeaway is that smart contract storage is basically a huge array. So there's no "allocation" or "creation" involved. When you write `User storage user = users[id]`, that just gives you a local reference to that location in storage.

If you wrote `User memory user = users[id];`, you would instead end up with an in-memory *copy* of that `User`.

`User storage user = User(5,10);` is a problem because `User storage user` declares a *storage reference*. (Think of it as a pointer to something in storage.) The right-hand side of the assignment should be something in storage so `user` can refer to that.

Comment: So a) if I write User storage user = users[id], where is user variable created? I think you said it got created nowhere. It's just a reference. how can't it be created somewhere? can't storage reference variable point to something that is in memory?

Comment: In the compiled bytecode, the location in storage is probably pushed onto the stack somewhere at runtime. No, a _storage_ reference can't point to something in memory. (It can only refer to storage.)

Comment: why do you think User storage user = User(5,10); the right side of this statement User(5,10) gets created in memory and not in storage? because it's in the function ?

Comment: What would it mean to "create" it in storage? I think you're assuming some sort of allocation (finding a free spot in storage and writing the data there), which is not how storage works.

Comment: So I finally understand it somehow. The only part missing for me is where reference variables are stored. User storage user where is that user variable? on stack memory? i don't think so. That's what ethereum says : local variables of struct, array or mapping type reference storage by default. so user reference variable is also in storage , but it says no allocation happens on storage . then what do I assume?

Comment: "so user reference variable is also in storage" No, the variable _references_ storage. It's up to the compiler to decide how to keep track of what that variable refers to, but I believe it will typically just push a storage location onto the stack.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82192/discussion-between-giorgi-lagidze-and-smarx).

Comment: So you believe that any reference variable (pointing to memory storage or storage) goes to stack memory right?

Comment: No. There's no such thing as "memory storage" or a reference variable pointing to memory in any way.

Comment: You said that User storage user (user is pointing to storage). I asked where that user that is pointing to data is stored. I know actual data is in storage, but i am asking where user (that pointer) is stored. I think it's on stack as you mentioned. If i write User memory user , I also think that this pointer is also saved on stack.  If that's right, then I understand .

Comment: Yes, I believe what you just said is correct.